# How to make Houdini's Animation Worklet work?

Tags: javascript, animation, css-animations, web-animations, css-houdini

I finally got around to do some scroll-bound animation with the [Animation Worklet](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/10/animation-worklet), just to find out that [Surma's demo](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/houdini-samples/animation-worklet/twitter-header/) is not working. Not even the one in the [article](https://animation-worklet-article.glitch.me/index.html).

Is the API still behind a flag? Or did it change somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Yes Houdini's Animation Worklet API (and most Houdini's Worklet APIs) is still behind the `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features` flag.

```js
if( !('animationWorklet' in CSS) ) {
  console.error('CSS Animation Worklet API is not supported in this browser, you may have to enable it from chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features');
}
else {
  console.log('good to go');
}
```